# Why tensorflow dll is not running?

Tags: python, tensorflow, unity-game-engine

Foremost, I don't code.
But out of curiosity I started checking unity. I was trying a tutorial about AI learning in karting game using python and tensorflow, and I did everything in the video to get them installed (they said it was all I needed to run this tutorial).
So after setting up my virtual enviroment I ran this

```
C:\Users\L\MyFirstGame>mlagents-learn Assets\Karting\Prefabs\AI\kart_mg_trainer_config.yaml --train --run-id=custom-track-1
```

and I got this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\l\myfirstgame\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "c:\users\l\myfirstgame\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "c:\users\l\myfirstgame\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\L\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\L\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.

During handling of the above exception another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\L\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\L\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\L\MyFirstGame\venv\Scripts\mlagents-learn.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\users\l\myfirstgame\venv\lib\site-packages\mlagents\trainers\learn.py", line 15, in <module>
    from mlagents import tf_utils
  File "c:\users\l\myfirstgame\venv\lib\site-packages\mlagents\tf_utils\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from mlagents.tf_utils.tf import tf as tf  # noqa
  File "c:\users\l\myfirstgame\venv\lib\site-packages\mlagents\tf_utils\tf.py", line 3, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf  # noqa I201
  File "c:\users\l\myfirstgame\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 98, in <module>
    from tensorflow_core import *
  File "c:\users\l\myfirstgame\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "c:\users\l\myfirstgame\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "c:\users\l\myfirstgame\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\Users\L\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "c:\users\l\myfirstgame\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "c:\users\l\myfirstgame\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\l\myfirstgame\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "c:\users\l\myfirstgame\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "c:\users\l\myfirstgame\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\L\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\L\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

For some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

I did check the tensorflow page with the solutions to the error but didn't help, so here I am.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to use tensorflow-gpu, but the error show tf can't load dll of cudnn.(I guess), maybe you not install cudnn or your tensorflow-gpu's version is not suitable for your gpu and cudnn.